# Why am I not able to see the services in this database through axis2 localhost?

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

I've been learning about web services and stuff and finally was able to build my first gimmick code, but whenever I try to create a web service of my DAO class on eclipse, I end up not being able to access it's sessions (Services, Validate, Administration) on localhost.

Additional info: I'm using axis2 with tomcat 6.0.41 (for tutorial's sake) and trying to access a recently created MySQL database "ExemploWS" through http://localhost:8080/ExemploWS/, which Works fine until I try to navigate through it.

Also using XAMPP Control Panel with Apache and MySQL started.
So I'm leaving the connection class and then the error I'm getting when accesssing http://localhost:8080/ExemploWS/services/listServices.

```
package br.com.ExemploWS;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConectaMySQL { 
private static final String url = "jdcb:mysql://localhost/exemplows";
private static final String user = "root";
private static final String pass = "";

public static Connection obtemConexao() throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
}
}
```

---

> HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet AxisServlet threw
>   exception
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Servlet.init() for servlet AxisServlet threw exception
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet AxisServlet
>   threw exception
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) root cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/ws/commons/schema/resolver/URIResolver
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:144)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.(RepositoryListener.java:61)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
>     org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
>     org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
>     org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) root cause
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:144)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.(RepositoryListener.java:61)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
>     org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
>     org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
>     org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
>     org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) note The full stack trace of the
>   root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.41 logs.
>
> Apache Tomcat/6.0.41'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this class to your application, it is missing:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/resolver/URIResolver
```

it is in commons-xmlschema, find it here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ws.commons.schema/XmlSchema

Comment: Thanks for replying! I ended up doing some research and found out I in fact needed a xmlschema class, but I used the core 2.0.2 instead of this one cause it was giving me faulty services (apparently something wrong with 1.4.7). Anyways, its working now.